# Prevent div from overlapping using height / min-height attribute

Tags: html, css

```
#userIDTableCell
{
   border-style:solid;
   border-color:#000;
   border-width:0px;
   min-height: 130px;
}
```

When I use the min-height attribute, the top div overlaps the bottom divs.. but when I remove it, then the bottom divs will move proportionally with the top div; which is what I want to happen when I set a min-height value.

The research I've done and the things I've tried don't seem to work. I've tried setting the other div's to relative and that doesn't work. Not sure how else to override this. I've also tried setting the div as a float..

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a fiddle ?

Comment: You need to, at the _very least_, post the relevant HTML. Demonstrating the problem in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is also very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set your height to auto if you are using the min-height attribute.

```
#userIDTableCell
{
   height: auto;
   border-style:solid;
   border-color:#000;
   border-width:0px;
   min-height: 130px;
}
```

Comment: Height could originally be a percent as well

Comment: This simple answer comes after 3 hours of failed attempts to make footer and expandable list to the bottom of the div all right!

Comment: @Aladdin glad I could help!